# Change Package directory in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to change the Package directory in Julia. The default is

```
"~/.julia/v0.4"
```

I want to *move* it to `/opt/julia/v0.4/`. Ideally I want to move the packages that are already installed in `~/.julia/v0.4` to the new location. But if that is not possible I can reinstall them.

What do I have to do?

Comment: you can run `export JULIA_PKGDIR=/opt/julia/v0.4` in shell, then use `Pkg.init()` to initialize a new package system in the new directory, and just copy and paste these packages to the new location.

Comment: I looked up `JULIA_PKGDIR` in the the [doc](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/pkg/). I should just set `JULIA_PKGDIR=/opt/julia`, since the version will be appended automatically. You should post an answer.

Comment: @GnimucK. I did this but it broke the Jupyter notebook. How can I alert Jupyter of the new location?

Comment: what's the result of `jupyter kernelspec list`?

Comment: @GnimucK. Nevermind. I fixed it by running `Pkg.build("IJulia")` in Julia.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## Julia-v0.6 and before

one can change julia's package directory by following these steps:

1. run `export JULIA_PKGDIR=/your/directory` in shell(or manually add a new environment variable `JULIA_PKGDIR` on windows)
2. run `Pkg.init()` in julia to initialize a new package system
3. copy `REQUIRE` from old directory to the new one
4. run `Pkg.resolve()` in julia

## Julia-v0.7+

The "Package directory" in the new package manager is called [`DEPOT_PATH`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/constants/#Base.DEPOT_PATH), it can be changed by adding an environment variable `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`:

```
JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=./test julia

julia> DEPOT_PATH
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "./test"

(v0.7) pkg> add JSON2
   Cloning default registries into /Users/gnimuc/test/registries
```

With the new package manager, we are able to create isolated projects in any directory we want instead of having a single giant package directory. Every project contains a `Project.toml` and a `Manifest.toml` if it has some dependencies. These two files record and keep tracking the environment of the project.

### UPDATE

The following info might be obsoleted. I highly recommend to use [PkgTemplates.jl](https://github.com/invenia/PkgTemplates.jl) for generating projects in Julia-v1.0+.

#### Generate a new project

We can generate a new project in any folder, but we must `cd` to the project folder to `using` the project. The `(v0.7)` below shows we're still in the default environment, so we cannot use the newly generated project:

```
(v0.7) pkg> generate ./MyNewProject
Generating project MyNewProject:
    ./MyNewProject/Project.toml
    ./MyNewProject/src/MyNewProject.jl

julia> using MyNewProject
ERROR: ArgumentError: Module MyNewProject not found in current path.
Run `Pkg.add("MyNewProject")` to install the MyNewProject package.
Stacktrace:
 [1] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:868
```

If we `cd` to the project folder and `activate` the environment, then we can `using` our new project without any problems:

```
shell> cd MyNewProject/
/Users/gnimuc/MyNewProject

(v0.7) pkg> activate .

(MyNewProject) pkg> 

julia> using MyNewProject
```

I think that's the big difference between the new package manager and the old one. In short, we need to explicitly `activate` our unregistered project/package.

#### Download and init someone else's project

According to the doc, we can add an unregistered package/project via `add` command:

```
(HelloWorld) pkg> add https://github.com/fredrikekre/ImportMacros.jl
```

This command adds the target package as a dependency of our current project. In this example, we added `ImportMacros` in `HelloWorld`'s `Manifest.toml`. What if we just use it as a top-level project? To add it to the default environment `(v0.7)`? no, we don't need to. The answer is we can directly download the code, `cd` to the folder and run `instantiate` in the pkg mode:

```
shell> git clone https://github.com/Gnimuc/GLTF.jl GLTF
Cloning into 'GLTF'...
remote: Counting objects: 286, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (56/56), done.
remote: Total 286 (delta 73), reused 103 (delta 59), pack-reused 167
Receiving objects: 100% (286/286), 62.16 KiB | 46.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (135/135), done.

shell> cd GLTF

pkg> activate .

(GLTF) pkg> instantiate
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
```

The new package manager is great! We neither need "`include` before `using`" nor make everything as a package just for `using` it. We have full-featured "Project" now!

Comment: If you have IJulia, run `Pkg.build("IJulia")` after.

Comment: Your update kinda gave me hope for what I want to do. I'm on windows and whenever I do a `Pkg.add` or `add` in `pkg` mode, all these packages go to `~/.julia` which I do not want. I thought I can isolate the packages to my project using your method, but apperently not.

Comment: @Vivere Could you elaborate a bit more about your use case? All dependencies are cached in the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` and these packages are isolated from each other. When developing your own package, you could `activate` to an isolated environment without any version collision problems. To me, it looks like your goal is to publish the package and pack all its dependencies. PackageCompiler.jl is the right tool for this.

Answer (score 5):

Julia only way:

```
julia> ENV["JULIA_PKGDIR"] = "E:\\Julia-0.6.0\\portable"
"E:\\Julia-0.6.0\\portable"

julia> ENV["JULIA_PKGDIR"]
"E:\\Julia-0.6.0\\portable"

julia> Pkg.init()
INFO: Initializing package repository E:\Julia-0.6.0\portable\v0.6
INFO: Cloning METADATA from https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
```

However, the cache dir is still pointing to the old folder, so I checked why that is and figured it out:

```
julia> Base.LOAD_CACHE_PATH
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "C:\\Users\\kung\\.julia\\lib\\v0.6"

julia> Pkg.__init__()
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "E:\\Julia-0.6.0\\portable\\lib\\v0.6"
 "C:\\Users\\kung\\.julia\\lib\\v0.6"

julia> pop!(Base.LOAD_CACHE_PATH)
"C:\\Users\\kung\\.julia\\lib\\v0.6"

julia> Base.LOAD_CACHE_PATH
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "E:\\Julia-0.6.0\\portable\\lib\\v0.6"
```

As simple function:

```
function set_julia_dir(dir::String)
    ENV["JULIA_PKGDIR"] = dir
    Pkg.init()
    Pkg.__init__()
    pop!(Base.LOAD_CACHE_PATH)
end

set_julia_dir("E:\\Julia-0.6.0\\portable")
```

Comment: Will this setting be preserved if I restart Julia?

Comment: The environment variable is only temporary, hence would need to call `set_julia_dir` every time

Comment: If you don't want to set JULIA_PKGDIR in your shell startup script, the only way is to edit Base, by default it's hardcoded to `joinpath(homedir(),".julia")` in `base/pkg/dir.jl` and then rebuild the system image of Julia