# move packages to different directory Julia 0.7

Tags: julia

I would like to move ~/.julia/packages to the julia installation directory. 
What else should I move ?
What env variables should I set?

JULIA_PKGDIR?
JULIA_DEPOT_PATH?
JULIA_LOAD_PATH?

push!(DEPOT_PATH, "newdirname") created registries and compiled directories. but any newly added packages are not getting installed in the "newdirname" directory.

export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH="newdirname" removed ~/.julia/packages and replaced with the new one. packages started getting installed in the new dir. Now when I move the entire installation with the packages to a different machine without internet, Julia forces me to rebuild the packages and then fails because there is no connectivity. so what would make this move work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new path by putting the statement

```
push!(DEPOT_PATH, "newdirname")
```

in startup.jl.

CAUTION: Most of the installed code in the .julia directories will have text created at installation containing pathnames to your old directories! I'd expect a *lot* of installed modules to break their installed state if moved. The adding via push! to DEPOT_PATH is for *adding additional* places to load files, NOT for moving *existing* installations!

Comment: So, if I push! and then start installing new packages, will they be installed in the new directory from then on

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398629/change-package-directory-in-julia and set JULIA_PKGDIR in your environment prior to starting Julia. Be prepared to rebuild the packages that break if moved.

Comment: JULIA_PKGDIR was for older versions. DEPOT_PATH sort of worked. then I moved entire installation with packages to different machine without internet and then usage fails again due to rebuilds