# Dead kernel error when opening a notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I had to reinstall a newer version of Julia because the earlier version got broke. Having installed a newer version of Julia, I upgraded to the newer kernel on Jupyter; unfortunately, when I open an existing Julia notebook, the kernel automatically dies.

Following a suggestion from this [link](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1892) I issued this command

```
conda remove ipykernel
```

to resolve the problem; because I don't have sudo rights the following error was thrown:

```
CondaIOError: Missing write permissions in ...
```

Is there is a way to resolve this issue without creating a virtual environment?

Following your @xiaodai and @Przemyslaw Szufel suggestions, I'm halted by this error

```
using IJulia
[ Info: Precompiling IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a]
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package ZMQ [c2297ded-f4af-51ae-bb23-16f91089e4e1] is required but does not seem to be installed:
 - Run `Pkg.instantiate()` to install all recorded dependencies.

Stacktrace:
 [1] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:929
 [2] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:858
 [3] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:853
 [4] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [5] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [6] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [7] top-level scope at none:2
 [8] eval at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [9] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:404
 [10] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /storage/home/julia_depot/packages/IJulia/9ajf8/src/IJulia.jl:36
ERROR: Failed to precompile IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a] to /storage/home/julia_depot/compiled/v1.1/IJu
lia/nfu7T.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1197
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:960
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:858
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:853
```

I have as suggested by the error message issued

```
Pkg.instantiate()
```

Also, I have tried

```
using ZMQ
ERROR: ArgumentError: Package ZMQ [c2297ded-f4af-51ae-bb23-16f91089e4e1] is required but does not seem to be installed:
 - Run `Pkg.instantiate()` to install all recorded dependencies.
```

Although, ZMQ has been installed.

Comment: Just `]add ZMQ;` and then if it still fails try `]build ZMQ`

Comment: Tried, doesn't work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Anaconda built-into Julia to start the jupyter notebook. In this way you will not have administrative rights nor configure virtual env to manage your Python installation.

```
julia> ]
(v1.0) pkg> add IJulia

julia> using IJulia
julia> notebook()
```

Actually you can also run the Julia Jupyter notebook outside of Julia console!

Windows (note that paths on your system might be different):

```
C:\> %userprofile%\.julia\packages\Conda\hsaaN\deps\usr\Scripts\jupyter-notebook
```

Linux (note that paths on your system might be different, this should also work on OSX):

```
$ ~/.julia/packages/Conda/hsaaN/deps/usr/bin/jupyter notebook
```

Comment: I have updated the error message that I receive after issuing `using IJulia`

Comment: My julia directory has only one folder named logs in it

Comment: its `.julia` not `julia` and is usually in your home folder. And looking at your updated error I recommed delete `.julia` and reinstalling all packages.

Comment: `xxxx@comp-ic-0011 .julia]$ ls
logs
`These are the only contents of .julia. I had deleted .julia earlier, and after that I realized that it broke due to some other reasons unknown to me; following which I upgraded to Julia 1.1.0 and now I'm stuck with this dead kernel error.

Comment: you need to find out the location of `.julia` and delete it. Maybe you are using JULIA_DEPOT_PATH variable?

Comment: Also have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398629/change-package-directory-in-julia to find out location of Julia folders

Comment: Yes, I'm using the JULIA_DEPOT_PATH variable. Could you let me know how deleting .julia would be helpful and how would it be replaced?

Comment: I have deleted .julia which was containing logs. No resolution after this. Same story persists: Julia runs from REPL but dies when a kernel is started.

Comment: In that case remove all files in the folder where JULIA_DEPOT_PATH  points to and reinstall packages

Answer (score 1):

I have this happen to me often. You can try to follow @Przemyslaw's advice and remove the folders or try this

```
]update
]build IJulia
using IJulia
notebook()
```

Typically `add` builds the IJulia, but I find that sometimes after updating, running `build` manually can help resolve the dead kernel issue.

Comment: I have updated the error message that I receive after issuing `using IJulia`