# Conda Python 3.7: ERROR: KeyError: key "JULIA_PKGDIR" not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, julia

I am trying to upgrade to python 3.7 by:

```
conda install python=3.7 anaconda=custom
```

However, I am getting the following error related to Julia DPKG:

```
Executing transaction: - ERROR: KeyError: key "JULIA_PKGDIR" not found
Stacktrace:
[1] (::getfield(Base, Symbol("##417#418")))(::String) at ./env.jl:76
```

Finally, I am unable to upgrade. Any idea how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**
I have solved this issue by doing the following:

1) Uninstall anaconda by

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
```

2) Download and install again anaconda (it will install anaconda with python 3.7 by default)

Comment: There is not enough information in this question. However, you can try to set system path as described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398629/change-package-directory-in-julia

Comment: Please, let me know what additional information should I include.

Comment: JULIA_PKGDIR is not used in Julia anymore - what version of Julia are you using. Your command is bash but your error is Julia - it is not clear from your question what is happening in between. Which Conda are you running this bash command against to? Julia in-built conda? Try to update the qeustion to be more specific.