# How to install portable packages with Julia?

Tags: julia, portable-applications, pluto.jl

I have Julia 1.9.2 installed (current stable release) in a portable fashion. (The .zip file julialang.org offers). It's extracted to an external flash drive (E:\Julia-1.9.2\...) due to university computer restrictions. How do I install a package within the portable Julia install? I would like to leave no trace of Julia on the host computer and keep everything within the external flash drive.

That is, instead of

```
julia> import Pkg; Pkg.add("Pluto")
    Updating registry at `C:\Users\...`
```

I would like to see

```
julia> import Pkg; Pkg.add("Pluto")
    Updating registry at `E:\Julia-1.9.2\...`
```

Comment: There should be environmental variables for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set the variable

   ```
   set JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=E:\Julia-1.9.2\...
   ```
2. Run Julia
3. Version info should show something like:

   ```
   julia> versioninfo()
   Julia Version 1.9.2
   ...
   Environment:
     JULIA_DEPOT_PATH = E:\Julia-1.9.2\...
   ```
4. Install packages - now they will end up at the `E:\Julia-1.9.2\...`

Comment: Is there a way to do this after opening Julia? I've since found the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/44918155/ and I'm not sure what caches I would need to refresh if I set `ENV["JULIA_DEPOT_PATH"] = "E:\\Julia-1.9.2\..."`. Or in that case, should I by pass the `$JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` entirely and go with `$JULIA_PKGDIR`?